# How can i set up Celery on a Flask application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery

I'm trying to setup Celery on my Flask application. To do so, i followed [this example](http://this%20example).

So here is what i did:

**main.py**

```
# Celery configuration
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

The problem is that, whenever i try to start the celery process, i get the following error:

```
celery -A app.celery worker

Error:
Unable to load celery application.
The module app was not found.
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: `celery -A main.celery worker`: You called the file `main.py`

Comment: I tried that too, but unfortunately it didn't work either

Comment: Should be filename.celery. so if the module name is, say, my_app/config.py, then use `celery -A my_app.config.celery worker`